# Animating with a for loop?

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop

I am using a for loop to add multiple objects to the stage, from there I would like to animate them but when I try only one of the balls move.

Here is my code.

*(Ball is pulled from an external class)*

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {

        private var ball:Ball;
        private var ax:Number = 4;

        public function Main()
        {
            init();
        }
        private function init():void
        {
            for(var i:Number = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                ball = new Ball();
                ball.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                ball.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
                addChild(ball);
            }

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame1);
        }
        private function onEnterFrame1(event:Event):void
        {
            ball.x += ax;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should push all your objects into array and change x property for each ball.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var ball:Ball;
        private var ax:Number = 4;

        private var balls:Array;

        public function Main()
        {
            init();
        }

        private function init():void
        {
            balls = new Array();
            for(var i:Number = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                ball = new Ball();
                ball.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                ball.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
                addChild(ball);

                balls.push(ball);
            }

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame1);
        }
        private function onEnterFrame1(event:Event):void
        {
            for(var i:int = 0; i < balls.length; i++)
            {
                balls[i].x += ax;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oof, onEnterFrame1 is bad naming. When giving example code, you might just as wel fix it right away ;)

Comment: Thanks that worked!!! OK so why do we push the ball into the balls array? Is it because an array can contain more then one object?

Comment: OK another thing in the onEnterFrame1 function, Why do we put i < balls.length? and the [i] in balls[i].x += ax;?

Answer (score 0):

**To create 10 balls**

1. remove the `private var ball:Ball;`
2. add a `var ball:Ball;` in the init method, juste before the *for*.

If you don't do so, the *ball* object, wich belongs to your Main class, is just updated 10 times in your loop but you still get only one object.

**Animating 10 balls**

You have to save your balls in a container, wich has to belong to your Main since you'r going to acces it from several functions of your class.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends MovieClip
    {
        private var ballsContainer:MovieClip;
        private var ax:Number;

        public function Main()
        {
            init();
        }

        private function init():void
        {
            ax = 4;

            ballsContainer = new MovieClip();
            addChild(ballsContainer);

            var ball:Ball;
            for (var i:Number = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                ball = new Ball();
                ball.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                ball.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
                ballsContainer.addChild(ball);
            }

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame1);
        }

        private function onEnterFrame1(event:Event):void
        {          
            for (var i:Number = 0; i < ballsContainer.numChildren; i++)
            {
                Ball(ballsContainer.getChildAt(i)).x += ax;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do so, you will get error, because you cannot use local variable from init() into another method.

Comment: It is overkill to use MovieClip instead of Array in this case. ;)

Comment: In most cases it's overkill, unless you want to rotate/translate/scale all balls by a certain amount. Then you could use the movieclip

Comment: Or, in this case `Sprite` would be more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You could let ball handle it's own movement.

```
package
{
  import flash.display.MovieClip;
  import flash.events.Event;
  import flash.utils.getTimer;
  public class Ball extends MovieClip {
    private var currentTime = getTimer();
    public function Ball(){
       addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
    }
    private function onEnterFrame1(event:Event):void {
      diff = currentTime - prevTime;
      x += diff *  ax 
      prevTime = currentTime;//update for next go around
    }
  }
}
```

So, why use a timer instead of a frame to animate? Well, you don't have to, but you can't always be sure of what time is in between two frames. In this case, your speed is always constant, even though your frame rate is not.

Comment: If the number of balls is large it is a bad idea to let each ball have its own ENTER_FRAME loop as it may degrade performance (1 vs n (number of balls) event object creations per frame).

Comment: True, but as I don't know what it is that he exactly wants to do, I've given a general solution that is used in games.