# Animating with a for loop part 2

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have another question thats has been bugging me. It's kinda a follow up from my other question ["Animating with a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880842/animating-with-a-for-loop)" Ok so I have that down, but how could I animate each ball to go randomly around the stage and not follow each other?

Here is my code:
*ball is pulled from an external class named Ball.*

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Dummy extends Sprite
    {

        private var balls:Array;
        private var ball:Ball;
        private var ballNum: Number = 10;

        private var ax:Number = 4;

        public function Dummy()
        {
            init();
        }
        private function init():void
        {
            balls = new Array();
            for(var i:Number = 0; i < ballNum; i++)
            {
                ball = new Ball(Math.random() * 30);
                ball.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                ball.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
                addChild(ball);

                balls.push(ball);
            }
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }

        protected function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
        {
            for(var i:int = 0; i < balls.length; i++)
            {
                balls[i].x += ax;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give each ball object a different direction and use that to move the ball instead of the `ax` value.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class Dummy extends Sprite
    {

        private var balls:Array;
        private var ball:Ball;
        private var ballNum: Number = 10;

        private var directions:Array = [new Point(-1,-1),new Point(0,-1),new Point(1,-1),
                                new Point(-1,0),new Point(1,0),
                                new Point(-1,1),new Point(0,1),new Point(1,1)];

        public function Dummy()
        {
            init();
        }
        private function init():void
        {
            balls = new Array();

            for(var i:Number = 0; i < ballNum; i++)
            {
                ball = new Ball(Math.random() * 30);
                ball.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
                ball.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
                ball.direction = directions[Math.floor(Math.random()*directions.length)];
                addChild(ball);

                balls.push(ball);
            }
            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
        }

        protected function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
        {
            for(var i:int = 0; i < balls.length; i++)
            {
                balls[i].x += balls[i].direction.x;
                balls[i].y += balls[i].direction.y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but its giving me an error. here:
ball.direction = directions[Math.floor(Math.random()*directions.length)];

Comment: You need to add a `var direction:Point` member to your ball class.

Comment: That did it, thanks a lot. But I don't really understand how it's happening. Can you help me understand or something

Comment: Basically I created an array that has the 8 possible directions the ball can go in called `directions`. Then inside the loop that is creating the balls I pick a random direction for each ball using the code `directions[Math.floor(Math.random()*directions.length)];` This assigns a random direction to that ball. Finally inside the `onEnterFrame` event the ball is moved using the random direction.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `Ball` class properties for speed, and a method `move()` that will adjust their respective coordinates, and probably will be enhanced to check for collisions sometimes later, so that your balls could rebound of walls for example.

```
// Ball class additions follow
private var vx:Number;
private var vy:Number;
public function Ball() {
    // ... original constructor here
    var angle:Number=Math.random(2.0*Math.PI); // random angle
    var vel:Number= MAX_VELOCITY*(0.5+0.5*Math.random()); // random velocity module
    // define this constant^
    vx=vel*Math.cos(angle);
    vy=vel*Math.sin(angle); // composites of velocity
} 
public function move():void {
    this.x+=vx;
    this.y+=vy;
}

// main class
    protected function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
    {
        for(var i:int = 0; i < balls.length; i++)
        {
            balls[i].move();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, im getting an error here:
`var angle:Number=Math.random(2.0*Math.PI); // random angle
   var vel:Number= MAX_VELOCITY*(0.5+0.5*Math.random()); // random velocity module`

Comment: You have to declare the constant. Yours, Captain Obvious.